# How can I create website with transferring file to Ubuntu server

Tags: python

I would like to upload two text files via web page, and transfer them to my ubuntu server. Then I want to add them into one file on the server, and receive it from server. So I can download the file on the web page.

I was trying to find some django and flask framework to do what i want, but i couldn't find it.

Could you recommend some reference to my question, or example?

Comment: By "add" do you mean concatenating the two text files? Is this a one-time use or should the result file also be available for download later on?

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding. You're exactly right. I want to concatenate the two text file, and download the result file later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it seems to be an overkill, either Django or Flask can do the job.

Taking Django as an example, you can set up you `models` to include two [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#filefield) to store the user uploaded files for future use.

You then need to specify the two FileField in `forms` as a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/).

As for `views` you'll need a view to handle upload and a view to handle download of concatenated text (assuming the content is generated when user requests the download).

If you plan to do this using a framework it's recommended that you read through at least the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/) of the Django documentation.